# Dynamic dropdown options for primeng and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

Hello guys I'm fairly new in Angular and I need help while adding / removing dropdown options dynamically from primeng.

Requirement:
I have a list of cities. If I select a city in the first dropdown, this particular city should be hidden when I add new dropdown, and so on such that the last dropdown only has one option left. This should work in the reverse order aswell when I remove dropdowns the selected value from the removed dropdown should appear again.

Example:
If I select `New York` then click on Add City, `New York` should be hidden from the newly generated dropdowns. If I remove `New York` then `New York` should appear again the rest of the dropdown options.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nysrdr

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown) tp understand how PrimeNg DropDown component works.

I suggest you, to follow this step

1. Create a List of cities; say `citiesList`
2. Pass this list as `Options` for the first dropdown
3. Create a new list for each of the dropdowns you are going to create; say `citiesListDD2` and populate it with all the `cities` initially
4. Associate `onChange` event for each dropdown
5. Update the array associated with each DropDown based on `selected value` from a dropdown, in the method that is called when `onChange` event is triggered

Note that this is just a high-level solution for solving the problem